# parsing url in Python

Tags: python, url

I have a url string (path + query-params) like this:

```
/go.asp?svid=9&id=17473576&tpages=1&ttimes=1&tzone=-8&tcolor=32&sSize=800,600&referrer=&vpage=http%3A//www.asunx.com/num3.html&vvtime=1454612377824
```

I want to parse it and get an output like this:

```
["/go.asp", "?svid=", "&id=", "&tpages=", "&ttimes=", "&tzone=", "&tcolor=", "&sSize=", "&referrer=", "&vpage=http://www.asunx.com/num3.html", "&vvtime="]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    url_q_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(in_str).query)
    In [4]: k1 = url_q_dict.keys()

    In [5]: k1
    Out[5]:
    ['tpages',
     'vpage',
     'ttimes',
     'tzone',
     'svid',
     'sSize',
     'tcolor',
     'vvtime',
     'id']

    In [6]: out_list = []

    In [7]: for text in k1:
       ...:     out_list.append("&"+text+"=")
       ...:

    In [8]: out_list
    Out[8]:
    ['&tpages=',
     '&vpage=',
     '&ttimes=',
     '&tzone=',
     '&svid=',
     '&sSize=',
     '&tcolor=',
     '&vvtime=',
     '&id=']

In [9]: url_split = urlparse.urlsplit(k)

In [10]: if url_split:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         path = url_split.path
    ...:     except:
    ...:         print "some error"
    ...:     else:
    ...:         out_list.append(path)
    ...:
    ...:

In [11]: out_list
Out[11]:
['&tpages=',
 '&vpage=',
 '&ttimes=',
 '&tzone=',
 '&svid=',
 '&sSize=',
 '&tcolor=',
 '&vvtime=',
 '&id=',
 '/go.asp']

In [12]:
```

Please note that the output I want must have "?svid" in the list...instead of "&svid". is there an elegant way to do it?

In general, the very first query-param that begins with a question-mark must be nicely represented in the output list.

Thanks.
PS: I am exploring furl library of Python too...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Maybe there's a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: in short, I am trying to generate a NIDS rule for a given pkt that will have some of the above keys (query params...). A typical rule will look something like this: content:"/go.asp?svid="; http_raw_uri; content:"&id="; http_raw_uri; content:"&tpages=";.....

Comment: It's not necessarily guaranteed that the query parameters come in that order is it?'

Comment: that is right. No guarantee of order.